# UNION from multiple lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a `class book` that has a property `IEnumerable<string> Tags`:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(string title, IEnumerable<string> tags)
        => (Title, Tags) = (title, tags);

    public string Title { get; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; }
}
```

Now I have `IEnumerable<Book> books` and I need to get only the common tags between **ALL** objects.

```
public static void TestMethod()
{
    var book1 = new Book("Book1", new List<string> { "c#", ".net", "programming" });
    var book2 = new Book("Book2", new List<string> { "ado", "c#" });
    var book3 = new Book("Book3", new List<string> { "programming", "c#" });
    var book4 = new Book("Book4", new List<string> { "ef-core", "database", ".net" });
    var book5 = new Book("Book5", new List<string> { ".net", "visual-studio", "c#", "programming" });

    var list1 = new List<Book> { book1, book2, book3 };
    var list2 = new List<Book> { book1, book3, book5 };
    var list3 = new List<Book> { book1, book4, book5 };
    var list4 = new List<Book> { book1, book2, book4 };


    // expected returns:
    // list1 => { "c#" }
    // list2 => { "c#", "programming" }
    // list3 => { ".net" }
    // list4 => { }

    Console.WriteLine($"list1 => {{{string.Join(';', GetCommonTags(list1))}}}");
    Console.WriteLine($"list2 => {{{string.Join(';', GetCommonTags(list2))}}}");
    Console.WriteLine($"list3 => {{{string.Join(';', GetCommonTags(list3))}}}");
    Console.WriteLine($"list4 => {{{string.Join(';', GetCommonTags(list4))}}}");
}
```

I really don't know the right way to do this. Until that moment, I do it in this horrible way (in Brazil, we call this "gambiarra", or "Workaround" in english):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCommonTags(IEnumerable<Book> books)
{
    var allTags = books.SelectMany(b => b.Tags).Distinct();
    var commonTags = new List<string>();

    foreach (var tag in allTags)
    {
        var isCommonTag = true;
        foreach (var book in books)
        {
            if (!book.Tags.Contains(tag))
            {
                isCommonTag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isCommonTag) commonTags.Add(tag);
    }

    return commonTags;
}
```

It's working, but how to do this right, or maybe with linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `All` linq operation

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCommonTags(IEnumerable<Book> books)
{
    var allTags = books.SelectMany(b => b.Tags).Distinct()
                     .Where(t => books.All(b => b.Tags.Contains(t)));
    return allTags;
}
```

The above code first gets all the `Tags` and validate if tag is part of `books collection` using [All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0) which determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

You can check this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/aHzyP0 which demonstrates your scenario.

Comment: Seems like that would be O(n^2) on `books.Count()`?

Answer (score 1):

A `HashSet<Tag>` would be efficient here, and only requires one pass:

```
var result = new HashSet(b[0].Tags);   //Init with first book
for(var i = 1; i < b.Count; i++)
    result.IntersectWith(b[i].Tags);
```

If `b` is an `IEnumerable` it's a little more complicated.

Comment: I tried. Changed to IList to work, but the results were

list1 => {c#;.net;programming}
list2 => {c#;.net;programming}
list3 => {c#;.net;programming}
list4 => {c#;.net;programming}

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Aggregate` method, you can `Intersect` across all the tags, using the `default(IEnumerable<string>)` as a flag to pick up the first set of `Tags`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetCommonTags(IEnumerable<Book> books)
    => books.Aggregate(default(IEnumerable<string>),
                       (commonTags, book) => commonTags == default(IEnumerable<string>)
                                                ? book.Tags
                                                : commonTags.Intersect(book.Tags));
```

Comment: Thanks @NetMage, I really liked your solution and learned a new way today :). I've not used `Aggregate` before so will read about. Thanks.

Comment: @user1672994 `Aggregate` has some interesting uses, it is comparable to APL reduce operator (`/`). Writing your own LINQ equivalent to the APL scan operator (``\``) can also be useful for concise LINQ processing.